# firebase.initializeApp() vs FirebaseApp.initializeApp()

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo

I currently trying to set up push notifications using the Notifications package from 'expo-notifications', Im just getting the following error and I cant work around it:

> [Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method getDevicePushTokenAsync on module ExpoPushTokenManager: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.-----.-----. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.]

The thing is, this message is completely enraging me because I do call:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
```

and after that:

```
firebase.initializeApp(ApiKeys);
```

at the start of my app.

Do I now need to install the Firebase/App package so I can do `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()`? Do I need to initialize my app 2 times then?

Neither the docs from expo are mentioning such an error, nor I found anything related to this error in the firebase docs and Im really struggling with this one.

Comment: You should only need to initialize it once. However, it seems that wherever `getDevicePushTokenAsync` is being executed, it is being called **before** your call to `initializeApp` OR it is using a different instance of `FirebaseApp` (e.g. uses a custom name). You'll need to investigate why this is the case, paying particular attention to the order of your imports. Some files might be imported & executed before your main file has.

Comment: I mean Im loggin into firebase with an account through my app and also retrieving infos from the database, and this happens after my ```initializeApp()``` call, thats what makes it extra hard for me to locate the error. 

How can I be able to log in with my firebase account inside my app and comunicate with the servers, if my app would not be initialized?

Comment: nevermind, I solved it, will put the answer to this problem down here. I still appriciate your answer and it made me understand my code better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aperently there is an import into the app/build.gradle file which is not mentioned inside the expo docs at all. Its the following line which is missing:

`implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-iid")`

you need to put it inside your app/build.gradle file to make it work.

[I found it in the following forum, the posts are just one month old so its a quite new bug.](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-android/issues/744)